# How to change libx264 profile when using ffmpeg backend of OpenCV

Tags: opencv, ffmpeg, libx264

I am using OpenCV 3.0.0 beta to write a video with
    `VideoWriter vw("out.avi",VideoWriter::fourcc('h','2','6','4'),24,frame.size());`

This calls on the ffmpeg backend (avcodec version 56.26.100), which calls libx264 (build 142). However, apparently it is not possible to specify a libx264 profile from OpenCV, and the default bitrate is too low for my application.

Where can I change the default behaviour of ffmpeg or possibly libx264 to get higher quality video written from OpenCV?

Answer (score 2):

Meanwhile, I found the answer myself. On line 1232 of modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp (on OpenCV 3.0.0 beta) the default CRF is defined as 23:

```
av_opt_set(c->priv_data,"crf","23", 0);
```

Change the number to the value of your liking. This requires recompiling OpenCV and it is a global setting until the videoio module properly implements codec options.